# Consulta con el arreglo (jsonarryay y volley)

Tags: android-studio

esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien siguiendo con la aplicación que estoy realizando, anteriormente rescato el dato de la fecha ingresado con anterioridad en otro fragment, ahora al ingresar el valor de un edittext, que puede ser de cero a diez, realizo la siguiente consulta:

```
private void llenarSpinner1() {
    String url = "http://192.168.1.89/oficina/buscar_uf4.php?Dia_UF=" + txtfecha.getText().toString();
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    txtfecha.setText(jsonObject.getString("Dia_UF"));
                    et_deducible2.setText(jsonObject.getString("Valor_UF"));
                    if (et_deducible.getText().length() == 0){
                        int a = 0;
                        et_deducible2.setText(a);
                        et_patente.requestFocus();
                    } else {
                        Double a = Double.parseDouble(et_deducible1.getText().toString());
                        Double b = Double.parseDouble(et_deducible.getText().toString());
                        Long c = Math.round(a * b);
                        et_deducible2.setText(c.toString());
                        et_patente.requestFocus();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error de conexión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

al ingresar la fecha que sé que no tengo ingresada en la base de datos me arroja automáticamente para afuera, lo que quiero o pretendo es que me mande un mensaje que no existe tal fecha ingresada.
Por otro lado, este es el utilizado en php, puede ser que se mejore este código y lo mencione aquí.

```
<?php
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');

require("conexion1.php");

$conexion = retornarConexion();
$Dias = $_GET ['Dia_UF'] ?? NULL;
$datos = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT Dia_UF,Valor_UF,Activo from valores_uf Where Dia_UF = '$Dias'
and Activo = 1 Order By Dia_UF asc");
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_all($datos, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($resultado);
mysqli_close ($conexion);
?>
```

ojala que me puedan ayudar con esta consulta y desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: les comento que realizando las pruebas el día de hoy, me di cuenta que al ingresar la fecha que existe en la base de datos, también me arroja para afuera, este mismo código lo utilizo en un activity y no me da problema, y en este fragment lo da, puede ser que algunos comando no los acepte, lo he revisado el PHP y probado en postammn y no da ningún problema, incluso este mismo código lo probe en un activity y funciono muy bien, como figo puede ser que en los fragment no los acepte, mi duda que tengo, desde ya muchas gracias